# C# выдаёт null при попытке прочитать подключение из web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, mstest

Есть два проекта в общем регенте. 1 asp net , 2 mstest. Через mstest проверяется метод из проекта asp net, в котором читает строку подключения из web.config, но получаю null. Ссылка на родительский проект есть. Арр.config добавил в проект тестирования, там прописал conString, но это тоже не помогло.. есть предположения, что я не так делаю ?
Код теста

```
  [TestClass]
    public class CheckAccessTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Проверяет принадлежность к роли по маршруту
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void AllowAccess_ByRoute_()
        {
            string test_user = "mstest";
            string test_route = "/Admin";

            var result =  CheckAccess.AllowAccess_ByRoute(user_name: test_user, route: test_route);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(result);

        }
    }
```

Метод вызываемый из класса CheckAccess

```
public static class CheckAccess
{

    public static string CheckAccess_ConnectionString => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Base_DB_Connection"].ConnectionString;



 public static bool AllowAccess_ByRoute(string user_name, string route)
    {
        bool res = false;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CheckAccess_ConnectionString))
        {
```

Ошибка падает на строке
[image: Ошибка падает на строке]

Web.config выглядит так :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Дополнительные сведения о настройке приложения ASP.NET см. на странице
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433.
  -->

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Base_DB_Connection" connectionString="Data Source=0000;Initial Catalog=0000;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=0000;Password=0000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

App.config выглядит так :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Base_DB_Connection" connectionString="Data Source=0000;Initial Catalog=0000;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=0000;Password=0000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Прошу прощения, вчера не было возможности описать более подробно, сегодня описал проблему более подробно

Comment: Не добавляйте скрины, добавьте текстом ваши файлы конфигурации. А исключение у вас потому что `ConnectionStrings["Base_DB_Connection"]` - null. Посмотрите названия ключа в коде и в конфиг файле, сверьте.

Comment: Проблема не в название! Если запускать этот проект без тестов все работает нормально.

Comment: Конфиг замечательно видно из скрина, не вижу целесообразности выносить данные в текст, если есть вопросы по скринам, могу ответить более развернуто или прислать доп информацию

Comment: А тесты у вас где? В новом проекте? Возможно, вы просто не зарегистрировали в тестах файл конфига. В asp.net конфиг там как-то сам по умолчанию находится, а в тестах самому надо вроде как

Comment: Тесты и сам проект лежат в одном решение

Comment: Ссылка на проект добавлена в тесты

Comment: @ОлегУстинов нет, добавьте текстом, а секретную инфу просто удалите или замените текстом "тутчто-товажное". Я (как и многие) не хотим открывать новые две вкладки просто ради двух ваших скринов. У меня 3-4 окна браузера и в каждой по 15 вкладок, поэтому и просят не выкладывать код скринами

Comment: Да тесты в другом проекте. Это два проекта в одном решение

Comment: Я сказал не о solution (`.sln`), а о project (`.csproj`). ASP.NET само настраивает ConfigurationManager на некоторые значения по [умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#default-configuration). При создании проекта тестов этого не происходит.

Comment: Исправил скрины на код, если вам это чем-то поможет

Comment: Вы предлагаете прописать конфиги через .runsettings? или я вас не правильно понял

Comment: Добавил в тестовый проект файл RomexSMRMSTest.dll.config, который полностью копирует файл app.config, но это не помогло.. Создал также файл .runsettings в нем прописал configuration==>connectionStrings как в конфиге, результата 0 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил. @Aarnihauta оказался прав, потребовалось добавить в .csproj проекта mstest данный кусок кода

```
<Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="app.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\testhost.dll.config" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="app.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\testhost.x86.dll.config"/>
</Target>
```